# Make Python 2.6 see Django

Tags: python, django, centos, mod-wsgi

In a harrowing attempt to get mod_wsgi to run on CentOS 5.4, I've added Python 2.6 as an optional library following the [instructions here](http://binarysushi.com/blog/2009/aug/19/CentOS-5-3-python-2-5-virtualevn-mod-wsgi-and-mod-rpaf/). The configuration seems fine except that when trying to ping the server the Apache log prints this error:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=20033, process='otalo', application='127.0.0.1|'): Loading WSGI script '...django.wsgi'. 
[Sat Mar 27 16:11:45 2010] [error] [client 171.66.52.218] mod_wsgi (pid=20033): Target WSGI script '...django.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module. 
[Sat Mar 27 16:11:45 2010] [error] [client 171.66.52.218] mod_wsgi (pid=20033): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '...django.wsgi'. 
[Sat Mar 27 16:11:45 2010] [error] [client 171.66.52.218] Traceback (most recent call last): 
[Sat Mar 27 16:11:45 2010] [error] [client 171.66.52.218]   File "...django.wsgi", line 8, in <module> 
[Sat Mar 27 16:11:45 2010] [error] [client 171.66.52.218]     import django.core.handlers.wsgi 
[Sat Mar 27 16:11:45 2010] [error] [client 171.66.52.218] ImportError: No module named django.core.handlers.wsgi
```

when I go to my python2.6 install's command line and try 'import Django', the module is not found (ImportError). However, my default Python 2.4 installation (still working fine) is able to import successfully. How do I point Python 2.6 to Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install Django specifically with/for the Python version that's meant to use it -- installs for 2.4 and 2.6 are always going to be separate (they have to be -- there are incompatibilities in binary and bytecode formats!).  I don't know what, if any, possibilities CentOS offers for that -- I'd get Django's [sources](http://www.djangoproject.com/download/) and install from sources (which boils down to: download, tar, cd, and finally a simple `sudo python2.6 setup.py install` -- or however else you run your 2.6 install of Python).  Being a much better developer than I'm a system administrator, I always have a bias in favor of installing from sources for stuff that's really at the core of what I'm doing (especially Python versions and extensions).

Comment: That did it, thanks!

By the same logic I have to now go back and install other python plugins for the parallel install (MySQLdb, wadofstuff serializers, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I created a write up [link text](http://blog.timc3.com/2010/03/26/django-on-redhat-or-centos/) of my experiences of getting Django working on Redhat and and CentOS. I upgraded the version of python that I was using and started with init.d scripts.